# Hide NSWindowToolbarButton

Tags: cocoa, hide, toolbar

What do I have to do for hiding this `NSWindowToolbarButton` in windows with a `NSToolbar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a checkbox for this in the appearance section of the attributes tab of the inspector for a window in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I have it...

```
[NSWindow setShowsToolbarButton:NO]
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you ever need access to any of the window buttons, or to find out if a particular window even has a certain button, you can use `standardWindowButton:` Take a look at the corresponding [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/standardWindowButton:)